# Accessing remote directory by socket programming

Tags: java, file, sockets, directory, jtree

I tried to access remote computer directory(wrote server and client parts) and put in JTree so I use System.getProperty("user.dir")
`File root=new File(System.getProperty("file.separator"));

     FileTreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(root);

     jTree1.setModel(model);`
After I set jTree1, I send it over socket connection but I cannot take the remote directory, it prints out its own file directory.I tried to take all files paths to make Tree model by using recursion whether it is file or not. However it takes approximately 3 min. How can I solve this problem?

Receiving part of my code is:

```
TreeServer = new ServerSocket(805);
TreeSocket = TreeServer.accept();
in = TreeSocket.getInputStream();
TreeObjectInput = new ObjectInputStream(in);
fileTree = (JTree) TreeObjectInput.readObject();
TreeObjectInput.close();
in.close();
TreeServer.close();
```

Sending part of my code

```
Socket ConnectionSocket = new Socket(remoteIP,805); 
File root=new File(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
model = new FileTreeModel(root);
JTree2.setModel(root);
OutputStream os = ConnectionSocket.getOutputStream();  
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);    
oos.writeObject(JTree2);  
oos.close();  
os.close();
```

Comment: add the code that sends/receives the data

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use java's `File` API on the client side, it is allways local. You propably have to implement your own `javax.swing.tree.TreeModel`, that accesses your server side, which in turn can use the `File` API for the server's local files.